# Handling 404 status code on NotFound Layout for Blazor Server with render mode "Server"

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor Server app with **render-mode="Server"**

We define **NotFound** handling on **App.razor**:

```
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Error404Layout)">
                <h4>Not Found</h4>
            </LayoutView>
            <HeadContent>
                <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
            </HeadContent>
        </NotFound>
```

If I **GET** any nonexisting url, Error404Layout does it works, but the page returns **200** status code, which is absolutely wrong.

I tried to find solutions and there is solution for ServerPrerendered render-mode - to inject HttpContextAccessor on layout page and set status code.

But it will not work with render-mode Server, which is used in my case.

Here is the discussion on that:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28776

To save your time - they will implement it on .NET 8

As you understand this is very strange and creates huge problems with SEO.

Is there any workarounds to solve this?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't inject HttpContextAccessor at all within a Blazor Server app. See here why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components You can achieve this by creating a MiddleWare which returns a status code.

Comment: The Middleware will not work because it is not ServerPrerendered render mode. context.Response.HasStarted will always return true.